# calcHist() doesn't return green histogram as expected

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am using OpenCV on Ubuntu 12.04. No fancy IDEs. Just compiling and running from the command-line. This is my code for calculating the histogram of a colour image. "lion.jpg" is a colour image. This code heavily borrows from the Official OpenCV tutorial for histogram calculation. 
 I get the red and blue histograms just fine. But the green histogram is all haywire. [The image of the histogram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HofY7.png)

My code is:

```
#include"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include"opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
Mat img,b_hist,g_hist,r_hist;
vector<Mat> channels;
namedWindow("Histogram",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
int bins=256;
float range[]={0,255};
const float* histrange={range};
img=imread("lion.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
split(img,channels);
calcHist(&channels[0],1,0,Mat(),b_hist,1,&bins,&histrange,true,false);
calcHist(&channels[1],1,0,Mat(),g_hist,1,&bins,&histrange,true,false);
calcHist(&channels[2],1,0,Mat(),r_hist,1,&bins,&histrange,true,false);
Mat histimage(600,600,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));
normalize(b_hist,b_hist,0,histimage.rows,NORM_MINMAX,-1,Mat());
normalize(g_hist,g_hist,0,histimage.rows,NORM_MINMAX,-1,Mat());
normalize(r_hist,r_hist,0,histimage.rows,NORM_MINMAX,-1,Mat());
for(int i=0;i<bins;i++)
{
line(histimage,Point(2*i,histimage.rows-b_hist.at<float>(i)),Point(2*   (i+1),histimage.rows-b_hist.at<float>(i+1)),Scalar(255,0,0));
line(histimage,Point(2*1,histimage.rows-g_hist.at<float>(i)),Point(2*(i+1),histimage.rows-g_hist.at<float>(i+1)),Scalar(0,255,0));
line(histimage,Point(2*i,histimage.rows-r_hist.at<float>(i)),Point(2*(i+1),histimage.rows-r_hist.at<float>(i+1)),Scalar(0,0,255));
}
imshow("Histogram",histimage);
waitKey(0);
destroyWindow("Histogram");
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo

```
line(histimage,Point(2*1,histimage.rows-g_hist.at<float>(i)),Point(2*(i+1),histimage.rows-g_hist.at<float>(i+1)),Scalar(0,255,0));
```

Instead of correct

```
line(histimage,Point(2*i,histimage.rows-g_hist.at<float>(i)),Point(2*(i+1),histimage.rows-g_hist.at<float>(i+1)),Scalar(0,255,0));
```

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad, ok.